# How to create and use separate file for each language in angular-translate with requirejs-angularAMD?

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, angular-translate, angular-amd

Using **angualr-translate with requirejs**. Want to create separate files for each language (contains translate keys), for the time it is all in app.js.

Example- **app.js**

```
    define(['angularAMD', 'ngRoute','pascalprecht.translate'], function (angularAMD) {
    var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute','pascalprecht.translate']);  
    app.config(['$routeProvider','$translateProvider', function($routeProvider,$translateProvider){
    /* *************** routes *************** */
    //...........
    /* *************** routes *************** */
    /* angular translate */
             $translateProvider.translations('en', { 
                add_user: 'Add User',
                first_name:'First Name',
                last_name:'Last Name',
                //.....
                //IMPORTANT: more than 1000 translate keys...
                //.....
            });
            $translateProvider.translations('de', {
                add_user: 'Benutzer hinzufügen',
                first_name:'Vorname',
                last_name:'Last Name',
                //.....
                //IMPORTANT: more than 1000 translate keys...
                //.....
            });
     // Bootstrap Angular when DOM is ready
        return angularAMD.bootstrap(app);

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

For case you want to use js instead of JSON.

```
var app = angular.module('myModule', []);

app.config(function ($translateProvider) {
  $translateProvider.useLoader('customLoader', {
     // if you have some custom properties, go for it!
  });
});

app.factory('customLoader', function ($http, $q) {
    // return loaderFn
    return function (options) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        // do something with $http, $q and key to load localization files
        // or do something to load file with requireJS
        require(['en-US'], function(translation){
          var data = translation;
        }

        return deferred.resolve(data);
        // or
        return deferred.reject(options.key);
    };
});
```

*this is an modified example in the preference link of asynchronus-loading in the end of the answer (section `Using custom loader service`)*

### **OLD ANSWER**

**angular-translate** supports on-demand load for translation files. You don't need to use requireJS in this case.

Currenly this is my code in `app.config()`

```js
$translateProvider.useUrlLoader('/translate');
$translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
$translateProvider.fallbackLanguage('en');
```

all you need to do is setup url like below

`{your_host}/something-translate?lang={language_key}`

In my case, the server real url is like.

`localhost/translate?lang=en`

`localhost/translate?lang=fr`

`localhost/translate?lang=es`

...

Then in controller:

```js
$scope.translate = function (langKey){
    $translate.use(langKey);
}
```

Preference link:

https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/wiki/Asynchronous-loading#registering-asynchronous-loaders

https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/wiki/Extensions

Comment: @SujVan I forgot to mention this, it is an extension of angular translate https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/wiki/Extensions

Comment: The translations are in js file (Not in server file). See the code above, please!

Comment: @SujVan updated answer, please checkout the preference link `asynchronus-load` with section `Using custom loader service`